# Using an alias within a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use an SQL alias within a left join. While using the alias in the join, I get the error 'unknown a_alias column in on clause'
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
SELECT a as a_alias FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON a_alias = b
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm ever so sorry, I accidentally typed 'where' instead of 'on'

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the alias in a where or a join as it hasn't been evaluated yet. They're only available in aggregates and group by/order by/having clauses IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

The only aliases you can use in `ON` are any table aliases; the `SELECT` clause is first in the grammar, but is (usually) the *last* processing step; the projection you ask for in the `SELECT` clause is not available yet.  You cannot use column aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in an `ON` clause -- you need to specify the full column name.

Comment: Ah, I see. I shortened my query by a lot, the actual code I use is

    SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column_a, 'key') as a_alias FROM table_a ...

That's why I wanted to use an alias

Comment: Ended up just selecting the column I needed and decrypting it in the on clause. My problem is solved, thank you! :)

Comment: No problem.  Note that if you wanted to save the computation time (assuming that MySQL can't optimize away the second call) you could always execute the function in a subquery (`SELECT a_alias FROM (SELECT a AS a_alias FROM table_a) AS a_query LEFT JOIN table_b ON a_query.a_alias = table_b.b`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an alias in a query you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT a as a_alias
    FROM table_a
) ta
LEFT JOIN table_b 
    ON ta.a_alias = b
```

You can wrap your `SELECT ... FROM` in parentheses and then use the table alias and the column alias in your `JOIN`.